# Multiple writers and readers in microservices approach

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, microservices, scalability

I've spent some time today on stackoverflow.com and haven't found an answer for my challenge.

## The challenge

I would like to create a Spring Boot based microservice I can scale easily. That microservice will be writing some entries (e.g. Product) to database and reading them. This service will be deployed as a [k8s deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) . Microservice saves data in AWS RDS MySQL instance. I will be scaling the microservice by embedded k8s  Deployment mechanisms.

## Questions

1. How can I create an spring boot based app that will handle saving data across many threads and across many instances of the app?
2. I've read some posts that in that case there should be some queue and from the queue only once instance and one thread should save the data but I guess it's cumbersome. I expect that there will be more and more traffic and as a consequence -> more and more messages in a queue to process.
3. Can you recommend some books ideally about that problem (in my words "multithreading and multi-instances writes synchronization problem).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think there is a "1 size fits all" solution for these kind of systems. You'll need to describe the system more. As for your questions, you can have several threads or processes reading/writing to a database. Just make more database connections (a lot of this handled through connection pools in libraries these days). Queue's are really common for these kinds of systems, Kafka is a popular one, but again, it's hard to tell if queues/kafka is the right tool without knowing more. As for books, look for stuff on "horizontal scaling", I think this is the term you are looking for.

Comment: @BrennenSprimont I know it's a wide topic but in your example: if I use the e.g. 3 writers threads how I will sync them to do not make a lock / deadlock on a mysql table? How should I syncronize them?

Comment: These days, MySQL and just about every sql engine should be able to handle 3+ writer threads/processes without any problems. What do your insert statements look like? Are there any triggers? Are you manually locking in your insert statements or in a trigger? Have you made any major configuration changes from what came out of the box?

Comment: @BrennenSprimont I'm asking for now theoretically cause they biggest concern I have is that should it look like when developing microservices. I don't know if I should split microservice between readers-microservice and writers-microservice to be able to scale them independently. Also I don't know how I should do with the MySQL db. I will be using 2 tables not more. From time to time updates and inserts, mostry reads (simple selects with primary key).